# Which web-drivers do not check if you are using selenium so that you can log into a website?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get to log on to YouTube with selenium but I cant because as soon as I write my email I receive an error saying my web browser or my google app may not be secure, I have found some info but non told me which web browser to use to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Firefox.
To show the Google site that you are not a robot. You can use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import geckodriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
    '/Users/<user name>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxx.default-release')

profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
profile.update_preferences()
desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,
                           desired_capabilities=desired)
```

Use [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/255587/how-to-find-your-firefox-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20locations%20are%3A,%2FFirefox%2FProfiles%2Fxxxxxxxx.) if you need a help with finding your profile location.

If you have problems with `geckodriver_autoinstaller` just remove from the code above the following lines:

```
import geckodriver_autoinstaller

geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()
```

This still should work correct if you have installed and properly defined the `geckodriver` on your machine

Comment: I am receiving an error: `File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\site-packages\geckodriver_autoinstaller\utils.py", line 175, in download_geckodriver
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`

Comment: Ok: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\site-packages\geckodriver_autoinstaller\utils.py", line 175, in download_geckodriver
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
`

Comment: `File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)`

Comment: `File "C:\Users\cuerv\Downloads\My code\Imports\python 3.8.6\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/My code/Sandbloxer/Main.py", line 7, in <module>
    geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()
  `

Comment: So, the failure is on the `geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()` code line?

Comment: It seems like it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232768/discussion-between-bootre-and-prophet).