# Selenium web driver can't sign in to google,

Tags: selenium

***************Update Changes, problem remain*******************************

```
cheregeckodriver_autoinstaller.install()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("/Users/Toshiba/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/zq6j04pa.default")
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled",False)
profile.set_preference("useAutomationExtension", False)
profile.update_preferences()
desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

path = '/Users/Toshiba/Desktop/backup/PythonLearning/Learning/Selenium/geckodriver'
binary = FirefoxBinary("/Users/Toshiba/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe")
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
# options.add_argument('-incognito')
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path, firefox_profile=profile,     desired_capabilities=desired, firefox_binary=binary)

url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/"
wd.get(url)
# login to google
username_class = "whsOnd zHQkBf".replace(" ",".")
wd.find_element_by_class_name(username_class).send_keys(username)
time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 3))
btn_next_class = "VfPpkd-RLmnJb"
wd.find_elements_by_class_name(btn_next_class)[-1].click()
```

---

Problem

---

Automate testing software detected
Couldn't sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

Comment: Add reproducible code, language tag and stacktrace.

Comment: Please take a look to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653062/which-web-drivers-do-not-check-if-you-are-using-selenium-so-that-you-can-log-int. I already answered there to similar question.

Comment: Hi Prophet, I have updated my code and followed your guide from others post, but the problem still remain the same. I have edited my post with current code, what's going on then?